# RegEx to match string between delimiters or at the beginning or end

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I am processing a CSV file and want to search and replace strings as long as it is an exact match in the column. For example:

```
xxx,Apple,Green Apple,xxx,xxx
Apple,xxx,xxx,Apple,xxx
xxx,xxx,Fruit/Apple,xxx,Apple
```

I want to replace 'Apple' if it is the EXACT value in the column (if it is contained in text within another column, I do not want to replace). I cannot see how to do this with a single expression (maybe not possible?).

The desired output is:

```
xxx,GRAPE,Green Apple,xxx,xxx
GRAPE,xxx,xxx,GRAPE,xxx
xxx,xxx,Fruit/Apple,xxx,GRAPE
```

So the expression I want is: match the beginning of input OR a comma, followed by desired string, followed by a comma OR the end of input.

You cannot put ^ or $ in character classes, so I tried \A and \Z but that didn't work.

```
([\A,])Apple([\Z,])
```

This didn't work, sadly. Can I do this with one regular expression? Seems like this would be a common enough problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on your language, but if the one you use supports lookarounds, then you would use something like this:

```
(?<=,|^)Apple(?=,|$)
```

Replace with `GRAPE`.

Otherwise, you will have to put back the commas:

```
(^|,)Apple(,|$)
```

Or

```
(\A|,)Apple(,|\Z)
```

And replace with:

```
\1GRAPE\2
```

Or

```
$1GRAPE$2
```

Depending on what's supported.

The above are raw regex (and replacement) strings. Escape as necessary.

Note: The disadvatage with the latter solution is that it will not work on strings like:

```
xxx,Apple,Apple,xxx,xxx
```

Since the comma after the first `Apple` got consumed. You'd have to call the regex replacement at most twice if you have such cases.

---

Oh, and I forgot to mention, you can have some 'hybrids' since some language have different levels of support for lookbehinds (in all the below `^` and `\A`, `$` and `\Z`, `\1` and `$1` are interchangeable, just so I don't make it longer than it already is):

```
(?:(?<=,)|(?<=^))Apple(?=,|$)
```

For those where lookbehinds cannot be of variable width, replace with `GRAPE`.

```
(^|,)Apple(?=,|$)
```

And the above one for where lookaheads are supported but not lookbehinds. Replace with `\1Apple`.

Comment: Good point on "Apple,Apple". Your lookaround solutions are capturing the successive columns, but for some reason not capturing the last-columns. http://regex101.com/r/eR6yH4  Thoughts?

Comment: @KevinGwynn Woops, forgot to put the anchors there. It's a mix of the first regex and the second. Will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This does as you wish:

- Find what: `(^|,)(?:Apple)(,|$)`
- Replace with: `$1GRAPE$2`

This works on regex101, in all flavors.

http://regex101.com/r/iP6dZ8

Comment: Nice! For some reason it didn't dawn on me to try ()'s. It was important to verify using the '/m' modifier like your regex101 example does.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. Note @Jerry's comment regarding `Apple,Apple`.

Comment: Aw, man. Please think it all through before selecting your answer. It really stinks having a big green checkmark taken away from you. And I was just about to take it out to a late lunch.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share my original work-around (before the other answers), though it feels like more of a hack.

I simply prepend and append a comma on the string before doing the simpler:

```
/,Apple,/,GRAPE,/g
```

then cut off the first and last character.

PHP looks like:

```
$line = substr(preg_replace($search, $replace, ','.$line.','), 1, -1);
```

This still suffers from the problem of consecutive columns (e.g. ",Apple,Apple,").